# Shipping method (Bring Fraktguiden (Versjon 1.6.8)) is not working in magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento

I am not getting any shipping option in one page checkout. I already added and configured it . And I am using Norwegian language. Now i solved the problem in locale by changing special character. I used the following:

```
Ą &#260;
ą &#261;
Ć &#262;
ć &#263;
Ę &#280;
ę &#281;
Ł &#321;
ł &#322;
Ń &#323;
ń &#324;
Ó &Oacute;
ó &oacute;
Ś &#346;
ś &#347;
Ź &#377;
ź &#378;
Ż &#379;
ż &#380;
```

Comment: Please provide some code: what have you tried?

Comment: I am tring to implement this http://docs.trollweb.no/display/modules/Bring+Fraktguiden. By default code of magento

Comment: Don't make additions to your question in the comments... Update your question so it reflects a proper question for SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said in an earlier post you are using multistore.  On the admin/config/shipping methods page, change the view scope drop down (top left of the screen) to the Norweigan website/store view and enable shipping methods.

Comment: i did it but not getting success

Comment: have you tried all the shipping methods?  free shipping, flat rate etc?

Comment: yes free or flat are working properly

Comment: ok so it's very likely a problem with your configuration settings in Bring Fraktguiden.  Have you created an account and entered your registration code?

Comment: i just matiching registration code to this  http://docs.trollweb.no/display/modules/Bring+Fraktguiden . is it Bring Identifikasjon

Comment: Bring Identifikasjon is same in http://docs.trollweb.no/display/modules/Bring+Fraktguiden and my store. Botha have same 18c071c3-caa5-45b8-a3db-06566a62e0f1 . May be its by default

Comment: there is a link to get your own code right under that field.  might need to get your own.